# ERwin Relationship Migrated Attributes

Tags: entity-relationship, data-modeling

In erwin I have 2 tables as shown below.

```
Table_A
|ID|DATA|

TABLE_B
|A_ID|DATA|
```

I created a relationship between table A and table B. Erwin adds ID to table B. In the logical view I can suppress the migrated attribute (TABLE_B.ID) but I can't seem to find the option to suppress migrated attributes in the physical view.

Assuming you can't suppress it in the physical view is there any way to tell the relationship that ID and A_ID are the columns that are joined to form this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

After creating the relationship you can rename the migrated attribute and it won't rename the parent it was created from. It should also be noted that this rename can be different between the logical and physical views.

Another way to do it is to open the relationship's properties and under the "Rolename" tab set the Rolename. Whatever you set the rolename to is what the migrated attribute will be named.